# Ubuntu Server doesn't recognize full RAM

Tags: server, ram

I transfered my old laptop into a home server.
It has 4 GB ram on the motherboard, but I took another 4 GB from my old macbook.
Unfortunatelly it doesn't recognize 8 GB of ram, but only 4.

What should I do?

[image]

Comment: You've provided no OS & release details; so why ask here?   How much RAM a box can utilize depends on many factors, most being specific to the hardware/firmware on the box itself (ie. not related to the OS you'll run on it).

Comment: Please proof 1st that the 8 Gb is actually accepted by the hardware.

Comment: Look at `sudo lshw -C memory` and `sudo journalctl  -b 0` to see what the CPU thinks. Is the new RAM the same speed, bus width, timing, etc as the old? Reboot, hold down `Shift` to get the Advanced Menu, and boot into `memtest86++`. Does it see the new RAM? If so, let it run for a few hours.

Comment: Depending on how old your "old laptop" is, it may not be able to support more than 4gb of RAM.

Comment: Sticks of RAM are not like socks. It's very rare they can be mixed and matched. You will want to confirm that the stick from the MacBook is compatible with the other stick, otherwise the system will ignore it (or simply not boot, but that doesn't seem to be the issue here).

Comment: Have you checked your BIOS configuration to see the amount of RAM is recognized?

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided the brand and model of the laptop you are using but when you enter the BIOS setup, (Which is usually done by pressing `<F1>, <F2>, <F10>, <DEL> or <ESC>` key during powerup), The BIOS setup will display the amount of RAM detected. If whatever RAM you added is not detected there, then no operating system will recognize the memory you added because it is incompatible with your motherboard.